# Will echoing content from a simple XML loaded with PHP cause the page to show up in search results (SEO)?

Tags: seo, php, rss

I want to know if I'm using PHP right to create search friendly content. I'd like my images to start showing up in Google for my website, so I'm passing an RSS feed to PHP file using the `simplexml_load_file` command and writing content to the page with `echo`s.

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('~~RSSfeed~~');

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo  '<li>'. $item->description .'</li>';
}
```

Will displaying a list of images and text (there's other formatting and divs that I didn't include) make this content show up in search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google, and any search engine, see the resulting page as served over HTTP. They have no idea how that page is generated server-side. The same as an entirely static page. So Google should see this content and providing you aren't blocking it with robots.txt, meta tags or HTTP response headers, etc then Google should index it.

> Id like my images to start showing up in google

However, your question is a little confusing. If your on-page images previously did not show up in Google then there may be other problems.

Comment: my images did not previously show up in google because they were dynamicly added using javascript- the source was fairly blank becuase everything was added after using a json get/appendTo commands. Im using php now to load the images firs onto the page (i just started teaching myself php this week